# Почему база говорит что столбца header нет?

Tags: android

База общается с ListView через SimpleCursorAdapter. Вот код

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DB db;
SimpleCursorAdapter sca;
Cursor cursor;
ListView listView;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    db = new DB(this);
    db.open();

    cursor = db.getAllData();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    String[] from = new String[] { DB.COLUMN_PREV_IMG, DB.COLUMN_HEADER, DB.COLUMN_SHORT_TEXT, DB.COLUMN_DATE };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.prev_img, R.id.tvHeader, R.id.tvShortText, R.id.tvDate };

    sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, cursor, from, to);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(sca);

    //listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
    //blah
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // закрываем подключение при выходе
    db.close();
}
}
```

код DB.java

```
public class DB {

private static final String DB_NAME = "mydb";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 9;
private static final String DB_TABLE = "mytable";

public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_IMG = "img_id";
public static final String COLUMN_PREV_IMG = "prev_image_id";
public static final String COLUMN_LINK = "link";
public static final String COLUMN_HEADER = "header";
public static final String COLUMN_FULL_TEXT = "full_text";
public static final String COLUMN_SHORT_TEXT = "short_text";
public static final String COLUMN_DATE = "date";

private static final String DB_CREATE =
        "create table " + DB_TABLE + "("
                + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key," + COLUMN_IMG + " integer,"
                + COLUMN_PREV_IMG + " integer," + COLUMN_LINK + " text"
                + COLUMN_HEADER + " text," + COLUMN_FULL_TEXT + " text"
                + COLUMN_SHORT_TEXT + " text," + COLUMN_DATE + " text" + ");";

private final Context mCtx;


private DBHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase DB;

public DB(Context ctx) {
    mCtx = ctx;
}

// открыть подключение
public void open() {
    DBHelper = new DBHelper(mCtx, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    DB = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

// закрыть подключение
public void close() {
    if (DBHelper!=null) DBHelper.close();
}

// получить все данные из таблицы DB_TABLE
public Cursor getAllData() {
    return DB.query(DB_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
}

// добавить запись в DB_TABLE
public void addRec(int id, int img, int prevImg, String link, String header, String fullText,
                   String shortText, String date) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COLUMN_ID, id);
    cv.put(COLUMN_IMG, img);
    cv.put(COLUMN_PREV_IMG, prevImg);
    cv.put(COLUMN_LINK, link);
    cv.put(COLUMN_HEADER, header);
    cv.put(COLUMN_FULL_TEXT, fullText);
    cv.put(COLUMN_SHORT_TEXT, shortText);
    cv.put(COLUMN_DATE, date);
    DB.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);
}

// удалить запись из DB_TABLE
public void delRec(long id) {
    DB.delete(DB_TABLE, COLUMN_ID + " = " + id, null);
}

// класс по созданию и управлению БД
private class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory,
                    int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    // создаем и заполняем БД
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DB_CREATE);
        Log.d("myLogs", "Обновляемся");
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        // заполним таблицу
        cv.put("_id", 10);
        cv.put("img_id", R.drawable.first);
        cv.put("prev_img_id", R.drawable.first);
        cv.put("link", "blablaLink");
        cv.put("header", "title1");
        cv.put("full_text", "fulltext1");
        cv.put("short_text", "shorttext1");
        cv.put("date", "1456754040029");
        db.insert("mytable", null, cv);
        Log.d("myLogs", "Обновляемся");
        cv.put("_id", 11);
        cv.put("img_id", R.drawable.second);
        cv.put("prev_img_id", R.drawable.second);
        cv.put("link", "blablaLink2");
        cv.put("header", "title2");
        cv.put("full_text", "fulltext2");
        cv.put("short_text", "shorttext2");
        cv.put("date", "1456754030029");
        db.insert("mytable", null, cv);
        Log.d("myLogs", "Обновляемся 3");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if(oldVersion != newVersion) {
            Log.d("myLogs", "Обновляемся с версии " + oldVersion + " на версию " + newVersion);

            // Удаляем старую таблицу и создаём новую
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_TABLE);
            // Создаём новую таблицу
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Что мне говорит студия

```
1) table mytable has no column named header
02-29 11:54:11.004 3380-3380/ru.arcsinus.SalesBlast E/SQLiteDatabase: Error                 inserting img_id=2130837576 link=blablaLink2 date=1456754030029 full_text=fulltext2 header=title2 short_text=shorttext2 _id=11 prev_img_id=2130837576
```

02-29 11:54:11.004 3380-3380/ru.arcsinus.SalesBlast E/SQLiteDatabase: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table mytable has no column named header (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO mytable(img_id,link,date,full_text,header,short_text,_id,prev_img_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте запятую добавить в COLUMN_LINK + " text"

```
COLUMN_LINK + " text,"
```

Comment: Не помогло. Может где-то они лишние?

Comment: Я добавил запятые там где их не было и теперь приложение запускается но ничего не отображает.

Comment: Решил проблему. Я спутал prev_image_id и prev_img_id и с запятыми. Спасибо!